# Python 3, API example and testing

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-import

## Premise

I come from the *Lua* scripting language and I had a minor exposure to the *Java* programming language, which I've used for studying *Algorithms*, 4th ed. ([ref.](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/)).

In *Java*, I've become used to see one class per file, with a `main()` method for testing and showcasing the correct usage of the class' API.

Now, I'm moving toward *Python* 3, which seems to me a vague merge of my two previous worlds.

## Current set up

I've started developing a project: one main script and a collection of folders containing several classes (*Python*'s modules). Each and every class has, as I've been accustomed to, its own test and usage example, which run `if __name__ == '__main__'`, *i.e.* if the module is run as a script ([ref.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts)).

Enter *Python* 3 absolute `import` statement.
Now I am in troubles.
A specific module may require to access function from `project_root.utilis`.
In my IDE (*PyCharm*) I can simply do `from utils import blah` but this is **bad** because it looks firsh among my installed modules, and then in my current project.
Moreover, if I run my module from the terminal, it does not even work.
I ended up sym-linking the function `utils/blah.py` in some sub-folder...

Now I am aware there must be other testing and documenting standards, but I like to keep an example of my modules within the module itself, so that one knows how to use it. And I believe I'm not the first who uses this kind of workflow.

## Question

Can someone explain to me what is the best practice to document a module with testing examples that can be run within the same file?
What is the recommended alternative?

## Later findings

I just figured out that, in my IDE, local modules have a precedence vs. installed ones (I believe this is not what should happen by default). I am not sure why this happens, though.
To run my modules as script, from `project_root` I can `python -m module_dir.module_name`. At least I can remove the sym-links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is *best* is obviously a matter of opinion.
So I'm going to list some solutions in my ranking from worst to best.

Putting the tests in `__main__` is certainly one way. But you'll have to write the testing framework (e.g. reporting on passed and failed test) yourself. And it could very well be that the tests will outweigh the module code. It doesn't feel right to me to leave them in the module in that case.

Python comes with the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html) module. It is a port of Java's JUnit. It's quite verbose; you have to explicitly write classes for tests. This is the Java style shining through, I guess. Not very pythonic, IMO.

The [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html) module which extracts tests from docstrings is also part of the standard library. A plus point is that the docstrings do double duty; both as tests and as examples.

The [pytest](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) testing framework is much nicer. It will [automatically search and run many kinds of tests](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery) (including docstring tests). This is certainly *my* favorite testing solution.

Comment: Given that I'm after one (or more) example(s) that test the API and showcase the user how to use it, I think that the *doctest* you mentioned here is the best suited tool. Am I correct? (I've also just found out about the `-m` running modifier to temporarily savage my current setup.)